# SELECT WHERE fails (SQLITE)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to understand how this SQLite database manager behaves. It turns out that I want to do a simple select and the following is happening to me:

I have a "Qualifications" table (calificaciones in spanish) where when loading the program, I automatically insert 5 rows full of data (30 cells in total) of test to see how the queries behave:

CREATION OF THE TABLE:

```
   public static final String CREAR_TABLA_6="CREATE TABLE " + Tabla_Calificaciones + " (" +
            Columna_IdCalificacion + " " + VARCHAR_TYPE + "PRIMARY KEY" + COMM_SEP + " " +
            Columna_IdMateria + " " + VARCHAR_TYPE + COMM_SEP + " " +
            Columna_Categoria + " " + TEXT_TYPE + COMM_SEP + " " +
            Columna_Fecha + " " + DATE_TYPE + COMM_SEP + " " +
            Columna_Descripcion + " " + TEXT_TYPE + COMM_SEP + " " +
            Columna_Calificacion + " " + SMALLINT_TYPE + COMM_SEP + " " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + Columna_IdMateria + ") REFERENCES " + Tabla_Materias + "(" + Columna_IdMateria + "))";
```

DATA INSERT

```
admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_IdCalificacion,"1");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_IdMateria,"M001");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Categoria,"AP");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Fecha,"11-12-2017");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Descripcion,"Hacer un osito de goma pendejo");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Calificacion,"100");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_IdCalificacion,"2");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_IdMateria,"M001");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Categoria,"EI");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Fecha,"10-12-2017");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Descripcion,"Esto es un texto representando una descripcion " +
            "demasiada larga para colocarlo todo dentro de un textview :)");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Calificacion,"85");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_IdCalificacion,"3");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_IdMateria,"M001");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Categoria,"TG");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Fecha,"09-12-2017");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Descripcion,"Dibujar una valla");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Calificacion,"75");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_IdCalificacion,"4");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_IdMateria,"M001");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Categoria,"EP");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Fecha,"08-12-2017");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Descripcion,"Sabe mas bien");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Calificacion,"66");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_IdCalificacion,"5");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_IdMateria,"M001");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Categoria,"PF");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Fecha,"07-12-2017");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Descripcion,"Ow shet");
    admin.insertar(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,DBScheme.Columna_Calificacion,"55");
```

the code is a bit long, so I put something straight to the point. There you can see that I'm inserting data (and it loads perfect). Here I leave the code of the onCreate method of the class:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.men_detalle_cas);
    context = this;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    admin = new dbHelper(this);
    int txtSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,5, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinSec);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.seccion,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),extras.getString("ID"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    cursor = admin.selectLog(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,
            "",
            null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),parent.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(extras != null) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        setTableValues(context,admin.getTableValues(cursor),"AP");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        setTableValues(context,admin.getTableValues(cursor),"EI");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setTableValues(context,admin.getTableValues(cursor),"TG");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        setTableValues(context,admin.getTableValues(cursor),"EP");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        setTableValues(context,admin.getTableValues(cursor),"PF");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    tabla = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablaDetalles);
    params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0,(int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,30,getResources().getDisplayMetrics()),0,0);
}
```

Ok, where I do the query is concretely here:

```
cursor = admin.selectLog(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,
                "",
                null);
```

If I leave it like this, as it is here (without where clauses and arguments) the method throws all the records of the table (the 30 cells):

[image]

Now, if I add my where clauses and arguments like this:

```
cursor = admin.selectLog(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,
            "WHERE " + DBScheme.Columna_IdMateria + "=?",
            new String[]{extras.getString("ID")});
```

The query only yields 5 records (only 5 poor cells, instead of all the records ... although all the rows have the same code of subject "M001")

[image]

And the weirdest thing is that it does not load even a row of the table! I've already read that **rawQuery** is not recommended for the SQL Injection theme. But to tell the truth, it was a desperate move ... since equally with **Query** it does not work either.

This is the methods that Im using of my DBHelper class:

```
   public void insertar(String table, String column, String value){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(column, value);
    db.insert(table,null,values);
}

 public Cursor selectLog(String tabla,String where,String[]args){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    if(args != null)
       cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ tabla + " " + where ,args);
    else
       cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ tabla,null);
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor selectWhere(String table,String[]columns, String whereCols, String[]whereArgs){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table,columns,whereCols,whereArgs,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

How to solve this... Im so confused. Cursor is not like Datatable or resultSet :/

**EDIT:**
I did some test with **query** function, and this happens:

The method query if I'm not wrong: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

- The first parameter, is the name of the table.
- The second parameter, is the columns that I want to select.
- The third parameter, is the Where clause.
- The fourth parameter, is the selection args for where clause.
- The last 3 parameters are for **GroupBy, Having and OrderBy**

Ok, my query function would be in the following ways ... I did two tests: Select 4 Columns where IdSubject (IdMateria) is equal to "M001"

```
cursor = admin.selectWhere(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,
                new String[]{DBScheme.Columna_IdMateria,
                DBScheme.Columna_Fecha,
                DBScheme.Columna_Descripcion,
                DBScheme.Columna_Calificacion},
                DBScheme.Columna_IdMateria + "=?",
                new String[]{extras.getString("ID")});
```

When going through the results, it only shows me the ID of the subject and nothing else.

[image]

[image]

Now, Im going to select another thing:

```
 cursor = admin.selectWhere(DBScheme.Tabla_Calificaciones,
            new String[]{DBScheme.Columna_IdMateria,
            DBScheme.Columna_Fecha,
            DBScheme.Columna_Descripcion,
            DBScheme.Columna_Calificacion},
            DBScheme.Columna_Descripcion + "=?",
            new String[]{"Dibujar una valla"});
```

And the results are the same. Its like, the method only select columns from WHERE clause... And I'm sure this should not be like that.

[image]

Comment: did you try to check if your `extras.getString("ID")` has a value or not?

Comment: Yes, and is working... Extras has a value

Comment: What does the `insertar` function do?

Comment: Insert data to a table. I only have to give the table name, column name and the data